# Assets 2 not indexing

Tags: assets

I have installed Assets 2 on a 2.5.5 EE install.

I have tried to index the files, but it just sits there and does nothing. No loading bars display like on another website I have used this on.

I left it until the session expired, and nothing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I had to change the server because of another problem... and now assets is not updating indexes at all... assets 2.0.2 and EE 2.5.5. btw: I've deinstalled and reinstalled assets, I've logged in and out, the native files are ok.

Comment: As Stefan wrote below - it might be because of the cross-domain issues. Make sure that the AJAX requests are targeting the same domain that you are accessing the CP from. www.host.com and host.com in this case are considered different domains.

Answer (score 5):

OMG: I found the problem!

It's because in my .htaccess I added a www. and I set my base_url without www.

so it's just a www. or no www. issue for me! hope that helps!

cheers
stefan