# Assets File Manager not showing images

Tags: assets

I have the latest Assets on EE 2.5.5 and I'm not seeing the files in the File Manager. I have one upload destination called Uploads and in that, a number of subdirectories and files. When I update the index, it takes some time so it **looks** like it's found files, but the File Manager shows neither directories nor images.

All file permissions are fine and it appears to upload OK, I just can't browse and select anything. Any suggestions?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey Russ - you're on Assets 2.0.2?

Comment: Russ - also check out: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5197/assets-2-not-indexing - make sure that you don't have any cross-domain referencing issues!

Comment: Hi Lisa. I'm on 2.0.3 and I can't see any domain issues - Assets sees images in the root directory and I can create subdirectories with Assets - it's just not seeing some subdirectories that are already in place, if that makes sense

Comment: Any chance that I could login and have a look? If so, please send Superadmin and FTP details, and a link to this thread, to support@pixelandtonic.com.

Comment: Sure, I've emailed you with subject line 'Access details for SO question #5214'. Thanks, Lisa.

Comment: Hey Russ, that has not come through! Can you resend it please and leave a note here? You can copy it to lisa@pixelandtonic.com to make sure it gets through.  Thank you!

Comment: We had this problem last time - it's definitely in my sent mail so I've forwarded again. Have you got some spam filtering going on?

Comment: I don't, but you and one other person keep running into this.  Did you copy my lisa@ address? I haven't received your email there either. :(

Comment: Hey Russ - I see you're on 2.0.3, we're up to 2.0.5 - can you update and see if that alleviates the issues?  Thank you!

Comment: Just updated to 2.0.5 and now I'm getting a prompt to delete out of date entries in the database: "There are some entries in the database that are out of date - please select the ones that you want to delete below". These are the missing items but I don't want to delete them as that would mean I'd need to recreate them?

Comment: Hey Russ - From a response by Brandon on GetSat: "it’s saying that it has a record of a file that used to exist but doesn't anymore, and asking if you want to delete the record (and associated metadata / entry selections).  We give you the option because it's possible that you've just temporarily renamed/moved the file, but still want Assets to know about it. So we can't assume that the record should just get deleted."(https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/update_indexes_tells_me_some_entries_in_the_database_are_out_of_date)

Comment: Lisa, I've gone ahead and clicked on the Delete option and it didn't do anything - no error, no change in the Assets view, and the files and folders on the server aren't affected. I've emailed you login details again to support@ and lisa@. Please reply on here if you haven't received them again. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Russ - see my comment; this is for removing records in the database, not files in your filesystem. Basically Assets can't find the file, though it used to know about it, so it's asking you what to do.

Answer (score 1):

was having the exact same problem with ee2.6.1 and assets2.1.3.

After some deeper digging i found out assets created a new entry in the exp_assets_folders table where it remapped my parent directory to a new entry while deleting the orignal entry. Because of this all the other entrys where referring to the wrong parent_id.

Manually corrected this problem and that seemed to fix the problem.

With kind regard,
Bas van Ginkel